# Can't connect to the database out of the local host

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost

I've been trying to connect to database using this .php code:
My number port is 2086. The following code woks using the localhost bu not when I tried to run out of the localhost (on the live site).
There is only write "error" that strange that mysqli_connect_error() function doesn't return anything.
Can I find a solution ?

```
<?php

  if ($enlace = mysqli_connect("ip+port", "username", "password", "databases"))
        echo 'connect to the databases';
  else
    {
      printf("error", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: At least post the error message !

Comment: message is edited ! :)

Comment: of course; replace the printf() statement with `printf("error: %s", mysqli_connect_error());`

Comment: I suppose you did change all these parameters when you moved the code LIVE. They will probably all be different on a hosted server

Comment: how to know which parameters have I to put on my server ?
Finally there is any error, I just can't display the database contains.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
$enlace = mysqli_connect("ip+port", etc...
                            ^^^^^
```

is incorrect. port is specified as argument #5:

```
$enlace = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname, $port)
                                                                   ^^^^^
```

Comment: where's the signature RT?M ;-)

Comment: I would've, but the php.net page is a horrible mess of default args and whatnot for this function.

Comment: yea both `mysqli` and `PDO` are not documented very well in the manual

Comment: garsh... you're telling me.

Comment: sidenote: the port's optional, should they still have problems with it, and that another app's using the same port.

Comment: it's optional if the port's hard-coded into php.ini. but I'm guessing it's not, since 2086 is non-standard.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/printf you didn't provide a format character, so the error string can't be inserted. `printf('error: %s', mysqli_connect_error())`, or just `echo 'error', mysqli_connect_error()` would do just as well.

Answer (score 0):

It finally work !!
I changed the domain name of the site and it's works.
I think the problem is due to the old domain name.
I'm sent them a mail for try to find a solution.

thank you for all of you help